# Provision new azure VM based on Image backup

Tags: powershell, azure

I have created the Azure VM and taken successfully the backup of disk using powershell. Now i need to create another VM using that disk?

How to proceed with that. Also i wanted to do same using image also. My main goal is to take backup of vm using either disk or image and then able to create new VMs using those backups or update the existing vm using those backups

Answer (score 0):

The process you need to follow is covered here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amol/archive/2014/03/21/how-to-migrate-windows-azure-vm-from-one-region-to-another.aspx

Note that if you don't "sysprep" the source VM when you attempt to provision a new VM based on the VHD of the source VM it will provision but the Azure management portal will show Running (provisioning) for the host.

Comment: Thanks actually i am trying to automate. I got the solution on http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/17/step-by-step-templating-vms-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-and-powershell-31-days-of-servers-in-the-cloud-part-17-of-31.aspx